# I have hands all over me. What am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I have hands all over me
>   First I used balls, now I can see
>   Tied or not, I have no free will
>   Moving, moving, that's the key.

What am I?

Hope you enjoy this riddle.

Comment: there is a sign of this being a dirty riddle too.....

Comment: @wrangles how so?

Comment: @lois6b: In so, so, so many ways.

Comment: i can understand why you say so but...  it was not my intention lol

Comment: It can certainly be totally innocuous, but if you have that kind of mind, this can also sound like some sort of softcore beat (heh) poetry.  That being said, I like it. Good job. :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Is the answer:

> A computer mouse?

I have hands all over me:

> People use their hands to control the mouse

First I used balls, now I can see

> Mouses used to have a small ball, but now they have optical sensors

Tied or not, I have no free will

> Whether the mouse is wireless or not, it still can't do anything by itself

Moving, moving, that's the key

> You use the mouse to move your cursor (and click and scroll, of course...)

Comment: yes , it is correct.. ouch. as my first riddle, i 'll try to improve.

Comment: How intelligent !

Answer (score 11):

Are you

> a clock?

I have hands all over me

> there is an hour hand, a minute hand, and a second hand over the clock face.

First I used balls, now I can see

> I was thinking of clocks with [pendulums](http://clockway.com/mm5/merchant.mvc?screen=ctgy&category_code=wallclocks1210p) (swinging round weights) for the 'balls'.  As for being able to see - that might mean the eyes of a cuckoo clock (or other animal or face-themed clock with eyes).  It might mean the digital clocks, like those used in phones, which can synchronize to a standardized clock (ie, "see" the correct time), or an [atomic clock](http://www.wired.com/2014/04/nist-atomic-clock/) which can "see" and measure time with the natural resonance frequency of cesium.

Tied or not, I have no free will

> it's a common trope to be tied to the clock, that [time is beyond our control](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/keywords/clock.html) and ticks away regardless.  On the other hand, clocks themselves can only tell time, not change what is happening or even when it happens.  It might refer to a [self-winding clock](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/gadgets/clocks-watches/question285.htm), which can swing its own gears to wind the spring, but has no free will to change its time or measurement.  Or it is possibly referring to [tide clocks](http://tideclocks.com/), which are clocks which track the sea tides.

Moving, moving, that's the key.

> My first thought was a pocket-watch, which needed to be wound (via a [key fob](http://www.ebay.com/gds/Vintage-Watch-Fob-Buying-Guide-/10000000177317426/g.html?rmvSB=true)) in order to keep moving.  However, it might just as easily refer to the use of any kind of [clock key](http://www.clockworks.com/clock-parts/clock-keys.html) or the constant motion of the watch hands.

You are a

> clock

Comment: Ehmmmmm the correct answer was already said. Thanks for trying tho

Comment: @lois6b - Ah, I saw there was another answer, but hadn't seen the comment confirming it as correct.  Sorry.  it was fun to puzzle through, though.

Answer (score 7):

For the lols

> A stripper

I have hands all over me

> Client's hands

First I used balls, now I can see

> Client's balls...or chinese, doesn't really fit with the 'now I can see' tho

Tied or not, I have no free will

> They are often tied, but even if they are not, they always have to satisfy someone's wishes

Moving, moving, that's the key.

> Never stop dancing, that's their job

PS: No machismo